# How can I import a landscape mesh?

Tags: unreal-4

I can export the landscape of UE4 (File -> Export Selected -> .obj / .fbx) and load a landscape, for example, in Maya. But how is the modified landscape loaded back into UE4? Otherwise, how to import terrain to UE4? Thank.

P.S.: Any format and any editor are interested.

Answer (score 1):

You may export it as *.fbx and import it again via the import dialog.

[image: import dialog img]

Comment: Unfortunately, when importing *.fbx it will be a mesh, but not terrain

Comment: Hey @Range, thanks for starting this conversation, i see, my answer is not answering your question perfectly, its a workaround. Have a nice day.